# WCF windows heavy job service

Tags: c#, wcf, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, task

I have created windows service for my application which is responsible for doing heavy job as below.

1. service is singleton, when service get started it loads all the
   basic things that needed in memory. When i check the memory in task
   manager it shows me arround 10 GB. (This is OK this is what i
   expect).
2. This service call C++ DLL's (DLLImport) to process files.
3. Client communicate to services through asynchronous mode.
4. This service creates files/images on disk (no DB operations performed by service).
5. I use Task class to process each input. I create new task for each input.

After running service for approx 24 hours I observed that it goes to out of memory and service stop after that. When i observed memory in task manager it goes to 27 GB from initial 10 GB.
For each run memory starts increasing from 10 GB to 13, 15, 16 ... and goes on.
It never comes down.
Can anyone face this kind of windows service behavior?

Note :- I have high end machine with 32 GB RAM.